# How do I get properties of a logged in user using Firebase Google sign-in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Google sign-in in my project:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
}).catch(function(error) { 
});
```

After I authenticated the user I want to get some its properties, such as: name, email.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the API documentation, [signInWithPopup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithpopup) yields a [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#usercredential) object that contains a `user` property with a [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html) object.  You can use that.  For your code, that's `result.user` in your promise callback.

You can also get the currently signed in user with [`firebase.auth.currentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#currentuser).

Comment: Thank you! I knew this, my problem is, that I don't know how do I get the name, and email.